# C++ 'switch' and 'while' loop

Tags: c++

I'm having a few problems correctly implementing a C++ `switch` statement within a `while` loop.

I'm testing for the char '0', yet when I press this key on my keyboard and hit enter, the loop still continues.

Why would this be? Could it be something to do with my keyboard or [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) set or something along those lines?

Here is my source:

```
#include "Character.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char tmp;
    Character* kite;
    kite = new Player();

    ////////////////////////////
    // Name
    ////////////////////////////
    cout << "\n\t\tPlease enter your name:\n\t\t";
    cin >> tmp;
    kite->setName(tmp);

    ////////////////////////////
    // Weapon
    ////////////////////////////
    cout << "\n\n\t\tPlease select your weapon of choice:\n";
    const int MAXITEMS = 3;
    string lastItem;
    string inventory[MAXITEMS] = {"Sword", "Staff", "Double Blades"};
    string replaceItem;
    string addItem;

    // Print what is in inventory to start with


    for (int i = 0; i < MAXITEMS; i++)
    {
        lastItem = inventory[i];
        cerr << "\t\t" << i << ") " << inventory[i] << endl;
    }

    bool done = false;
    char choice;
    cin >> choice;

    while (!done)
    {
        switch (choice)
        {
            case '0':
                kite->setWeapon(inventory[1]);
                done = true;
                break;
        }
        if (done) //I added this in lately to try to overcome issue
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;//exit code
}
```

Comment: You do know that you're only requesting input OUTSIDE the loop.. - So it only happens once? - Have you run the code through a debugger?

Comment: if you're having these kind of problems you should learn to use debugging. In this case the first thing I would do is implement 'default' and see whether your case really gets executed. For larger projects it's also helpful to write a small logging class to your needs which will help you to keep track of many things.

Comment: im sorry, thanks for the responses also. I placed in a default at the start but it exited right away :( thanks for the comments though, I placed it inside the while and its all working now :D so do I need that inner if statement to check it the bool has been set to true?

Comment: Not if your `while(!done)` checks it each time around.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not setting `choice` inside your loop.

Your code only reads `choice` beforehand, so if the first (and only) character it reads is `'0'`, it will exit on the first iteration.  However, if your first character is not `'0'`, it will not read anything else, it will just run forever.

If your program is hanging, I suspect it is getting some character that is not `'0'`.  You can verify/debug this by checking (via debugger or printing) what the actual value of `choice` is in the loop.

Answer (score 3):

`cin >> choice;` belongs inside the `while` loop.

Answer (score 2):

You have to put `cin >> choice;` *inside* the `while`-loop. Otherwise you're just testing the same `choice` for ever. And your later addition of `if (done) break ;`) has no effect -- the `while`-loop exits anyway if `done` is true.